# What are the effects of the various foods available in 7D2D?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

There are a lot of different foods available in 7 Days to Die.

What are the effects of all those items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know all the effects of various foods, have a look at this table:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╦════════╦══════╦═══════╦═══════════╦══════════════╗
║       Item       ║              Recipe              ║ Health ║ Food ║ Water ║  Wellness ║ Smell Radius ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬════════╬══════╬═══════╬═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ Charred Meat     ║  1x Raw meat                     ║      2 ║   10 ║  -5   ║  0.8      ║  Large       ║
║ Blueberry Pie    ║  Egg,Corn Meal, Blueberry,Water  ║      0 ║   10 ║  0    ║  0.8      ║  None        ║
║ Corn Bread       ║  Corn Meal, Water                ║      0 ║    5 ║  0    ║  0.4      ║  None        ║
║ Corn on the Cob  ║  Corn, Water                     ║      0 ║    3 ║  0    ║  0.08     ║  Small       ║
║ Boiled Egg       ║  Egg, Water                      ║      0 ║    4 ║  0    ║  0.32     ║  None        ║
║ Boiled Meat      ║  Raw Meat, Water                 ║      2 ║   10 ║  0    ║  0.8      ║  Small       ║
║ Vegetable Stew   ║  Potato, Corn, Mushroom, Water   ║      5 ║    7 ║  0    ║  0.1      ║  Extra Large ║
║ Meat Stew        ║  Raw Meat, Potato, Corn, Water   ║      5 ║   20 ║  0    ║  1.6      ║  Extra Large ║
║ Bacon and Eggs   ║  Egg, Raw Meat                   ║      3 ║   15 ║  0    ║  1        ║  None        ║
║ Grilled meat     ║  Raw Meat                        ║      2 ║   10 ║  -2   ║  0.8      ║  Medium      ║
║ Baked Potato     ║  Potato                          ║      0 ║    4 ║  0    ║  0        ║  None        ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════╩════════╩══════╩═══════╩═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: FWIW, Bacon and Eggs is my favorite -- relatively easy to get with pigs and birds nests, provides 1 wellness each, and doesn't smell in your inventory. (Unless alpha 13 changed that, haven't made a grill yet.)

Comment: @TimS. As you can see in the chart, it did not.

Comment: didn't see the scrollbar with the smell radius... very useful.

Comment: Perhaps one suggestion -- adding the cooking tool (pot/grill/etc) that is required to cook that food.

Comment: @TimS. Feel free to edit it in

Comment: @TimS. I rolled your edit back, it was simply wrong. There is no stick utensil at all anymore.

Comment: Oh yeah.... I forgot alpha 13 changed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build up your wellness, use the food with the best ratio of wellness to fullness.  Most give 0.4 wellness per 5 fullness, so go with that - meat if you're somewhere safe, boiled eggs and corn bread if you're on the run.